# Can a hash function be cyclic?

Tags: hash, sha-256

Is it possible for a hash function, SHA256 for example, to be a cyclic hash function, where the hash of the hash returns the original value?

Example:

```
SHA256(a) = b
SHA256(b) = a
```

Or in another form:

```
SHA256(SHA256(a)) = a
```

A math example would be

```
f(x) = 1/x
```

because f(5) = 1/5, and f(1/5) return the original 5. f(f(5)) = 5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I retrieve a re-hashed (hash) value, for instance by additional hashing?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/78395/can-i-retrieve-a-re-hashed-hash-value-for-instance-by-additional-hashing) [Cycles in SHA-256](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24623/18298)

Comment: Yes, the Cycles in SHA256 link in your answer was perfect. Thank you.